# Skill bar jquery - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Ok i got the html code this one :**

```html
<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="20%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #d35400;"><span>HTML5</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #e67e22;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">20%</div>
</div>
<!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="25%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #2980b9;"><span>CSS3</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #3498db;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">25%</div>
</div>
<!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="50%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #2c3e50;"><span>jQuery</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #2c3e50;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">50%</div>
</div>
<!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="40%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #46465e;"><span>PHP</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #5a68a5;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">40%</div>
</div>
<!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="75%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #333333;"><span>Wordpress</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #525252;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">75%</div>
</div>
<!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="100%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #27ae60;"><span>SEO</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #2ecc71;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">100%</div>
</div>
<!-- End Skill Bar -->

<div class="skillbar clearfix " data-percent="70%">
  <div class="skillbar-title" style="background: #124e8c;"><span>Photoshop</span></div>
  <div class="skillbar-bar" style="background: #4288d0;"></div>
  <div class="skill-bar-percent">70%</div>
</div>
<!-- End Skill Bar -->
```

**And the css one :**

```css
.skillbar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.4s linear;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  -webkit-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -moz-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -ms-transition-property: width, background-color;
  -o-transition-property: width, background-color;
  transition-property: width, background-color;
}

.skillbar-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 110px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #6adcfa;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.skillbar-title span {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.skillbar-bar {
  height: 35px;
  width: 0px;
  background: #6adcfa;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

.skill-bar-percent {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #ffffff;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

**And the js one :**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.skillbar').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
      width: jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
    }, 6000);
  });
});
```

**The skills bars does not animate / not filling.
I tried to call the js file in html like this :**

```html
<script src="skills.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Also i tried to do like this :**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.skillbar').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
      width: jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
    }, 6000);
  });
});</script>
```

**But still don't work.. and i got no ideea why..
And btw i'm a begginer in all this so please be pacient with me and try to explain me how i resolve it in detail.
Thanks you all and i hope i get over this because i'm stuck and i don't know what to do anymore .. or where i go wrong with the code.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does work, the issue is with how you include your javascript. Do you have jQuery included? If not, try to include a version of it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

I tried this with the first js snipped and it worked (I told jsfiddle to include jquery behind the scenes): https://jsfiddle.net/v21gak4q/

Answer (score 0):

First attach a jquery library

```
<script src="your link to js file or CDN link"></script>
```

Then change some css to show your skillbar-bar correctly (it current not showing exactly)

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.skillbar').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
      width: jQuery(this).attr('data-percent')
    }, 6000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can give some explanations to the OP so it knows for the next time? Teach a man to fish, not lend him one.